# directory size of a linux machine using python fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I am trying to print the directory size using python fabric. I used the below code

```
def getfilesize():
    with settings(user='hduser',password='cisco'):
        path='/app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput/'
        os.path.getsize(path)
```

but it throws me an error " no such file or directory"

But I can see this directory

```
hduser@dn1:~$ cd /app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput/
hduser@dn1:/app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput$ ls
taskTracker  tt_log_tmp  ttprivate  userlogs
```

Am i doing any sytax error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a syntax error, rather the python code is still being executed on your machine and not the remote machine. So calling `os.path.getsize` is checking the path size on your local machine (where it does not exist).

Instead you need to use fabric to execute shell commands on the remote server and catch their output. There are fabric modules that wrap common use cases, like the [files module](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/files.html), so you don't have to work in terms of bash commands. Unfortunately I don't know of any that will give you a recursive directory size. Fortunately, getting the size of a directory is just a oneliner so we can do something like:

```
def getfilesize():
    with settings(user='hduser', password='cisco'):
        output = run('du -s "/app/hadoop/tmp/myoutput/"')
        # output is the commands stdout as a (potentially multiline) string
        # for `du` it will look like: "183488582 /app/hadoop/tmp/mypoutput"
        size_in_bytes = int(output.split()[0])
```